# How to wait until all data is received to complete function in typescript/angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm testing to see how long it takes to query the data a certain amount of times.

Typescript:

```
public testRSS(){
    this.Service.getAllCustomerId().subscribe((data)=> {
      this.customerId = data;
      console.log(this.customerId.length)
      var i: number;
      for (i = 0; i < this.customerId.length; i++){
        this.Service.getFacilitesByCustomer(this.customerId[i].CustomerId).subscribe((data) => {
          this.facilities = data;
          console.log(this.facilities);
        })
      }   
    })
  }

  public rssPerfromance() {
    var t0 = performance.now();
    this.repeat(40);
    var t1 = performance.now();
    console.log("Call to testRSS() took " + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.")
  }

  public repeat(amount: number){
    var i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < amount; i++){
      this.testRSS();
    }
  }
```

It seems that the counting in my `rssPerformance()` function completes before all the data is received. How can I make it so that the millisecond count doesn't end until all the data is retrieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're experiencing here is JavaScript's asynchonous single-threaded event-loop, that is a departure from the way concurrency works in many other programming languages.

### TL;DR:

The best thing to do here would be to use Promises and async / await features:

```
  // Assuming the types CustomerId and Facilities have been defined

  public async testRSS() {
    const data = await new Promise<CustomerId[]>(resolve => {
      this.Service.getAllCustomerId().subscribe(resolve)
    });

    this.customerId = data;
    console.log(this.customerId.length);

    for (let i = 0; i < this.customerId.length; i++){
      const data = await new Promise<Facilities>(resolve => this.Service.getFacilitesByCustomer(this.customerId[i].CustomerId).subscribe(resolve));
      this.facilities = data;
      console.log(this.facilities);
    }
  }

  public async rssPerfromance() {
    var t0 = performance.now();
    await this.repeat(40);
    var t1 = performance.now();
    console.log("Call to testRSS() took " + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.")
  }

  public async repeat(amount: number){
    var i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < amount; i++){
      await this.testRSS();
    }
  }
```

### Longer Version

Javascript does not pause execution of code to handle long-running operations that are not CPU-bound (e.g. reading a file from disk, making a HTTP request, etc...). Instead, when you want to perform a task that may take an unknown amount of time, you start the task with instructions of what should be done when the task is complete. E.g, if you are loading a file over HTTP, you will give the instructions for how to load the file, and you will instruct it what to do with the file once it is loaded (and usually, what to do if the file failed to load, due to e.g. a network error).

The way you typically do this in JavaScript/TypeScript is by using callbacks. You are doing this in your example code when you pass the argument to `subscribe()`. In each case you are providing a function that should be run when the data is loaded.

Until recently (around 2013), this was the standard way to handle async operation in JavaScript, but this could often result in highly complex code, and what some refer to as [Callback Hell](http://callbackhell.com/).

To get around this situation, [Promises](https://web.dev/promises/) were introduced, and later on [async/await](https://medium.com/the-andela-way/introduction-to-async-await-its-best-practices-de4b30d11aa8). This can result in much clearer, and can allow you to effectively tell JavaScript to "pause" execution of code until an async task has been completed.