# How to wait until all data is generated in a child component using typescript/angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

How do I ... "Wait" for a data that is being accessed using `@ViewChild` from a parent component in a child component that is only accessed when a `event` is sent by this child component to the parent component?

So, for clarifying...
I have a custom form on a child component, that sends a event when a form is valid, like this:

```
// Event Emitter from Child Component.
@Output() formIsvValid = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
```

Whenever a value called "Valid" on a Form Component I am using becomes true, this event is sent to the parent component.

And, on parent component we receive this event on the Template, like this:

```
    <app-form-services #formRequestService
      (formIsValid)="ifFormIsValid($event)"
    ></app-form-services>
```

The method that I execute upon receiving this event, which is `ifFormIsValid`, enables a button that is not present inside the Child Component... It activates only when the event sent by our child component is received, like this:

```
  // Method inside Parent Component that enables values that activates buttons.ido.
  ifFormIsValid(event: boolean) {
    // TODO: Make sure that @ViewChild Form values are available/generated.
    this.formIsValid = event; // Update local validation form, for button.
    this.openServiceButton.disabled = !event; // Enables button according to event.
  }
```

So, so far we did:

1. Child sends event when form is valid.
2. Parent updates variable that enables my button for opening a service.

The only problem is that, the `Button` method, access the Form Data using `@ViewChild`, like this, with its Template Variable Reference:

```
@ViewChild(FormServiceComponent) private formRequestService!: FormServiceComponent;

// Access Form Data and Open Service Request (Inside "Open Service" method...)
openService(){
    this.parentFormData = this.formRequestService.formNewService.value
    // Etc - Rest of the logic is: I get specific values and send it using a API.
}
```

It is working, if I wait a little bit before clicking the "Open Service" button, but, if I am too fast, when I click the "Open Service" button I noticed that the values of the child form are still being created...

So, only after a couple of miliseconds the values of my child form are generated.
Before that, they are stored as `undefined`...

So, my question is:

How do I "wait" for its data to being available?

I tried the following method on this question:

[How to wait until all data is received to complete function in typescript/angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66607081/how-to-wait-until-all-data-is-received-to-complete-function-in-typescript-angula)

But I was not able to make it work, I also was not able to implement `Subscribe` and `Observable` for waiting for the data to be available. I used Async/Await on multiple parts of the code, but they did'nt do the job.

I also even tried to do a `while` and a setTimeout to wait a couple of seconds before procceeding, but it did'nt work as well. (The Set Timeout got ignored for some reason.).

Please, can someone give me some direction?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, if I understand the flow. Child component emits `isFormValid` when its false `openServiceButton` is enabled. On the click of which it attempts to fetch the form value in Child component. Question here is when and where do you emit `isFormValid`?

Comment: Hello @j4rey `isFormValid` is sent by Child component to Parent component when some criterias are met when filling some inputs inside my form. (The required fields). So, right after becoming valid (It's a logic from the form itself, it's not the Form Material but a very similar one), it emits the event saying the form is valid, so the Parent component can access the form values directly (Using @ViewChild.ChildForm.Values...). The problem is, it tries to do that exactly when the event is received, so the `Form` sends the event saying that it is valid BEFORE saving its data.

Comment: So, I just need to make sure that when receiving the event, I check if the @ViewChild.FormData.Value is generated, if it's still not (Because it occurs AFTER the Form Valid Event), I need to try again. I tried using `while` with a `cont` using 10 seconds, and I also tried using a setTimeout before trying to access the data, but it just got ignored.